# How to send header in one microservice to another microservice without changing payload in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs, microservices, send, emit

How to send header in one microservice to another microservice without changing payload data?

I want to send some specific header in microservice which is required me to another microservice.

Something like given below.

```
return await this.Client.send(MICRO_SERVICE_PATTERN, data, {
            context: { headers: responseHeaders },
        }).toPromise();
```

I expect that it should work as like I can send header in emit or send and then can get it in another microservice.

Comment: How can i set default data to micro-service payload anyone know that ?